# Capturing typeclass dictionaries

Tags: haskell, typeclass

Below is code that will happily compile (once adding the `constraints` package). `Foo1` and `Foo2` are two alternate definitions of `Foo`, which I can write `f1` and `f2` sensibly for.

However, I *think* `Foo3` is reasonable as well. Yet I don't know how to write `f3`. It seems to me that Haskell should store a pointer to the typeclass dictionary inside the `Foo3` constructor, for whatever `a` is passed when `Foo3` is created, so then I should be able to just call `silly`. Since `silly` just returns `String`, it doesn't matter if `a` has been erased by now, I should be able to happily call the `silly` pointed to by the dictionary stored in the constructor `Foo3`.

Is my reasoning right? And if so, how can I write `f3`. Alternative, have I missed something and is there a good reason why I need either `Dict` or `Proxy` here because without them I haven't got enough information?

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

import Data.Constraint (Dict(Dict), withDict)
import Data.Proxy (Proxy)

data Alice

class C a where
    silly :: String

instance C Alice where
    silly = "Silly Alice"

data Foo1 where
    Foo1 :: Dict (C a) -> Foo1

f1 :: Foo1 -> String
f1 (Foo1 (dict :: Dict (C a))) = withDict dict $ silly @a

data Foo2 where
    Foo2 :: C a => Proxy a -> Foo2

f2 :: Foo2 -> String
f2 (Foo2 (_ :: Proxy a)) = silly @a

data Foo3 where 
    Foo3 :: C a => Foo3

mkFoo3 :: forall a. C a => Foo3
mkFoo3 = Foo3 @a 

f3 :: Foo3 -> String
f3 = undefined
```

Answer (score 7):

With sufficient extensions turned on, and a sufficiently new GHC (9.2 seems to be new enough here, and maybe slightly older ones will work as well), the following works:

```
f3 (Foo3 @_ @a) = silly @a
```

What's that `@_`, you ask? There's an implicit kind argument, the kind of `a`, that we want to ignore. Alternately, you can use the `NoPolyKinds` extension and drop the `@_`.

Comment: Or to drop the `@_` quantify `{k}` to be inferred and `a` to be specified `Foo3 :: forall {k :: Type} (a :: k). C a => Foo3`

Comment: @Iceland_jack Have you tested that? Doesn't seem to work here. Indeed, `k` is already inferred by default with no annotation, but needs to be bound anyway.